# Is it possible to use an MOV instead of a flyback diode in a pulse circuit?

Tags: flyback, scr, mov

I am working on a small high-voltage pulse circuit to protect my animals. I have a question about the flyback diode D2 to protect the SCR.

The flyback diode seems to waste a lot of energy between pulses. Would it be possible to use an MOV which would only work when needed instead of dumping after every pulse?

I have attached a picture:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: What may be the purpose of C2 and D2?

Comment: It looks like you are charging C1 to 400 V and then triggering the SCR to discharge it to GND through C2 and T2. It is unclear how D2 functions as a flyback diode, and a 1N5408 may be too slow to be effective. It would be helpful if you could simulate it and explain just what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

No! If a MOV could serve the same purpose it would use the same energy. MOVs are not directional and are more similar to fuses than they are to diodes. They are much more subject to deterioration and failure.

Comment: I was thinking if the MOV was used it would only operate if a spike was above the rated voltage, where as the diode lets all reverse voltage to ground which seems a waste of energy